# What is the best practice for passing variable to entire module for use by all functions in package (in Python)?

Tags: python, function, variables, module, arguments

I am learning Python.
I have created a .py file for reading and writing to an excel spreadsheet. It has several functions, for writing, reading, saving, etc.
In a separate .py file, I want to call these functions. I would like to pass the variable of the filepath into this package. Is there a better way than individually passing the variable to each excel function? Can I pass the filepath variable as a whole to be share by all excel functions?

Comment: You can have all these functions in a class and only pass the filepath once when creating the object. Then each method call on that class object can access the path using an instance variable (like `self.path`)

Answer (score 1):

In the file with the functions create a module level variable that the functions use. In the second file, after importing, assign a new value to the variable in the first file.

a.py

```
var1 = 'one'
def f():
    print(var1)
def g():
    print(var1)
```

b.py

```
import a
a.var1 = 'two'
a.f()
a.g()
```

---

Using parameters with default arguments *in* the functions will not work; the parameter's value is bound when the function is *made* (when the module is imported) and subsequently reassigning `var1` will not affect `z` in the functions.
**this does NOT work**

```
var1 = 'one'
def f(z=var1):
    print(z)
def g(z=var1):
    print(z)
```

Comment: This is the solution I went this. Thanks